# How to get the MainActivity (ReactActivity) from within the ReactNativeHost within the ReactApplication

Tags: java, android, react-native

This question only refers to `react-native 0.29` and onwards:

Theres a module I'm using which requires me to pass the main activity to its constructor.

Up until react-native 29 I used to pass it like so:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new OrientationPackage(this), //<-------
    );
}
```

but now this part of the code has to be moved within `MainApplication` and I no longer know how to access the MainActivity from that part of the code..

This is how my `MainApplication.java` file looks now:

```
public class PlaceAVoteApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication{


    private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = new CallbackManager.Factory().create();

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        /**
         * A list of packages used by the app. If the app uses additional views
         * or modules besides the default ones, add more packages here.
         */
        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                    new MainReactPackage(),
                    new OrientationPackage(this), //<-- Error here because this is not the MainActivity


            );
        }
    };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage()
                ,new OrientationPackage(this)
        );
    }
};
```